# Boto3 S3 cp recursive from one region to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I am looking for a way to copy from an S3 bucket in one region to another S3 bucket in a different region via a python script.

I am able to do it using AWS CLI using:

```
aws s3 cp source-bucket  target-bucket --recursive --source-region region1 --region region2
```

However, I want to see if similar is possible within python script using boto3.

Whatever I have researched seems to work for same region using `boto3.resource` and `resource.meta.cleint.copy`

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 can only 'copy' one object at a time.

When you use that AWS CLI command, it first obtains a list of objects in the source bucket and then calls `copy_object()` once for each object to copy (it uses multithreading to do multiple copies simultaneously).

You can write your own python script to do the same thing. (In fact, the AWS CLI *is* a Python program!) Your code would also need to call [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) and then call [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) for each object to copy.

Given that the buckets are in different regions, you would send the commands to **destination region**, referencing the source region, for example:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='destination-region-id)
response = s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=..., Key=..., CopySource={'Bucket': 'source-bucket', 'Key': 'source-key'})
```